# Debugging Spring Cloud Dataflow apps

Tags: intellij-idea, spring-cloud-dataflow

I am fairly new to Spring so this might be a bit of a remedial question, but how does one attach a debugger to a custom SCDF stream app? I have found plenty of resources on how to do a remote debugging session for standard Spring apps using IntelliJ, but that doesn't help when its the local dataflow server that spins up the stream app (which has to be done if you are working with processors or sinks). I have found how to do essentially println statements so I can write debug statements to a console window but that is...sub optimal. I really need to be able to attach a debugger and see who's doing what to whom.

I'm sure there is something basic I am missing. Can someone just give me a gentle nudge on how to debug a source, processor and/or sink app, please?

Answer (score 0):

We have attempted to add support to debug SCDF orchestrated apps via [spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow#502](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/pull/502). We are revisiting the support for it, though. If you've any ideas around this, please feel free to submit a PR - we would happy to collaborate with you on that.

In the meantime, you could use [`--local.inheritLogging=true`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.2.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#_log_redirect) property to pipe all the application logs that belong in a stream to the server console. Once you've enabled `DEBUG` logs for the desired packages at each app level, you will be able to see the composite logs all in one console.